# Convert Lat/Lon to VicGrid94

Tags: c#, coordinate-system, convert

In C# how can i convert a Lat/Lon coordinate to Vicgrid94 which is described http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3111/ and also http://www.dse.vic.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0012/117102/VICGRID94MapProjectionInformation.pdf. The second link gives math examples of how to convert but is a little to much for me.

I am aware of JavaScript library's and the like, but i would prefer to do this in C#

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a .NET developer myself, but I found a couple resources that might help:

- [proj.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) is probably the best projections library around; there's a .NET wrapper that seems to be maintained quite regularly [here](http://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/Public/BDB/Tools/proj4/)
- there's another library, called [Proj.NET](http://projnet.codeplex.com/), but the latest build is more than two years old. It's supposed to support Lambert Conic Conformal projections.
- you could implement the projection yourself - i usually use either [the EPSG guidance note on coordinate conversions](http://www.epsg.org/guides/docs/G7-2.pdf) which uses formulae that can be easily converted to code, and contains examples that can be used to test the conversion; or Snyder's 1987 book [Map projections; a working manual](http://pubs.er.usgs.gov/usgspubs/pp/pp1395), but that one is a bit more mathematical.

P.S.: I don't know what CRS your Lat/Lon coordinates are in, but if they're in WGS84, you may need to do a datum conversion from WGS84 to GDA94 (depending on the accuracy required) - see [What is the difference between WGS84 and GDA94](http://www.icsm.gov.au/gda/wgs84fact.pdf)?